# dd-wrt automount usb storage after reboot

Tags: dd-wrt

Follow the dd-wrt howto about auto-mount usb storage, I correctly set the script but after reboot it does not runs.

```
nvram set rc_startup="
mount UUID="cc86da36-d6fd-445d-af1b-c08ded86ff00" /mnt/
"
```

after reboot usb device is not mounted. From webgui I've to restart "core usb support" everytime to automatically mount usb storage.

I use latest dd-wrt: v3.0-r30082 std (07/01/16)

Any idea to solve this (probably) bug?